# How to calculate time spent on every layer in CNN with caffe interface?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I was trying to calculate the time spent on every layer in fast-rcnn network. I found out that caffe cmd interface `caffe time` can do it. But the fast-rcnn is based on the python code, is there any function in the python interface can help me calculate the time ?

Answer (score 0):

python has profiling tools. You can look at [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) and the [`cProfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) tool.
If you are looking for something more basic, you can use `time` module to measure time:

```
import time
t = time.time()
run_rcnn_script()
dt = time.time()-t
print "time spent in run_rcnn_script: ", dt, " sec."
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate time spent at each layer

```
import timeit

t1=timeit.default_timer()
net.forward(start='start_layer_name',end='end_layer_name')
t2=timeit.default_timer()

print 'time is {}'.format(t2-t1)
```